# MySQL undo log keep growing

Tags: mysql, innodb

MySQL undo log is keep growing to 180G and there is no rollback records and I just cant figure out why. As far that I know, it will do auto truncate when it reach `innodb_max_undo_log_size` which have set to `1GB`. Any good solution for this? This is the query:
`SELECT Name, ALLOCATED_SIZE/1024/1024/1024 AS SIZE (GB)  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLESPACES  ORDER BY file_size DESC LIMIT 1;`

```
|Name           | SIZE (GB)        |
|innodb_undo_001 | 183.953220367432 |
```

[image]

What is the thing that I should check? Will restart MySQL service will reduce the undo log size? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for a transaction that is running for a very long time.

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
```

Now scroll to the last entries in the section

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
```

There you will see the longest running transactions. Here's an example:

```
---TRANSACTION 184428602997, ACTIVE 236 sec
8057 lock struct(s), heap size 980520, 2000277 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 124353057, OS thread handle 0x7ee6ef041700, query id 6717837828 10.20.30.40 a_mysql_username cleaning up
```

Here you see that the transaction runs for 236 seconds. When you do

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

you probably won't see it in there with the same time. In the processlist the time column gives you the seconds since the last status change in the transaction. When the transaction executes a new query, the timer is reset to 0.

Anyway, what you also see in the example above is the mysql thread id for this transaction. Use this to kill the thread.

```
mysql> kill 124353057;
```

And your problem should be solved. This will take quite some time (actually for 180GB it will take ages), as the transaction gets rolled back. The same would happen however if you would restart the server. Don't restart, your server will just be down for quite some time. Just kill the thread and wait.

Comment: Thank you so much, will the undo log size back to normal after kill the thread? Now I notice there are a lot of transaction being deleted and rolling back. @fancyPants. It shows `---TRANSACTION 20716380661, ACTIVE 3148 sec rollback of SQL statement
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
ROLLING BACK 497920 lock struct(s), heap size 52371664, 994926 row lock(s), undo log entries 179113 MySQL thread id 361723,`

Comment: And `---TRANSACTION 20710774756, ACTIVE 7961 sec rollback
ROLLING BACK 728195 lock struct(s), heap size 76570832, 1455036 row lock(s), undo log entries 292458 MySQL thread id 359783`. I need to kill all thread id?

Comment: I have tried to kill the thread id, but the transaction still there, not killed. @fancyPants

Comment: Yes, the undo log size will go back to normal. When threads are rolling back, just let them do their thing. Don't kill them (it doesn't work anyway).

Comment: Note it may take some time for the undo purge thread(s) to release the data in the undo log. It doesn't happen instantly.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-undo-tablespaces.html#truncate-undo-tablespace

```sql
-- Manual truncation of undo tablespaces requires a minimum of three active undo tablespaces. Two active undo tablespaces are required at all times to support the possibility that automated truncation is enabled. A minimum of three undo tablespaces satisfies this requirement while permitting an undo tablespace to be taken offline manually.
CREATE UNDO TABLESPACE temp_undo_003 ADD DATAFILE 'temp_undo_003.ibu';

ALTER UNDO TABLESPACE innodb_undo_001 SET INACTIVE;
-- wait for the state become 'empty'
SELECT NAME, STATE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLESPACES WHERE NAME = 'innodb_undo_001';
ALTER UNDO TABLESPACE innodb_undo_001 SET ACTIVE;
-- repeat above for innodb_undo_002

-- after innodb_undo_00{1,2} both cleared
ALTER UNDO TABLESPACE temp_undo_003 SET INACTIVE;
DROP UNDO TABLESPACE temp_undo_003;
```

or set [`innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency) to `1`